# dplyr : Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : argument 'times' incorrect

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a tibble as :

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  read_seq unique_id
     <chr>     <dbl>
1 AATTGGCC         1
2   GGGTTT         2
```

I want to create a new variable containing a string of the same size as read_seq. I did  that but have an error:

```
> r %>% mutate(y=paste(rep("H",width(read_seq)),sep=""))
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : argument 'times' incorrect
```

When I only try to catch read_seq width it works :

```
> r %>% mutate(y=width(read_seq))
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  read_seq unique_id     y
     <chr>     <dbl> <int>
1 AATTGGCC         1     8
2   GGGTTT         2     6
```

Here's the dput() of the example for reproducibility :

```
r <- structure(list(read_seq = c("AATTGGCC", "GGGTTT"), unique_id = c(1, 
2)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), .Names = c("read_seq", "unique_id"))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error comes from `rep`, the `times` parameter needs to be either 1 or the same length as `x`, which is not the case here:

```
rep("H", c(1,2))
Error in rep("H", c(1, 2)) : invalid 'times' argument
```

You can use `strrep` instead, which recycles `x` and `times` as necessary:

```
r %>% mutate(y = strrep("H",nchar(read_seq)))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  read_seq unique_id        y
#     <chr>     <dbl>    <chr>
#1 AATTGGCC         1 HHHHHHHH
#2   GGGTTT         2   HHHHHH
```

Or if you need some random strings of equal sizes, use `stringi::stri_rand_strings`:

```
r %>% mutate(y = stri_rand_strings(length(read_seq), nchar(read_seq)))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  read_seq unique_id        y
#     <chr>     <dbl>    <chr>
#1 AATTGGCC         1 H0flAbNS
#2   GGGTTT         2   QrQOLj
```